# how to install libsvn-perl in home directory?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a development server (ubuntu) without root privilege. And, our version control tool is svn but I prefer git. So I intend to use git svn sub-command to manage my code locally. But the problem is that git is not installed in the development server.

Yesterday, I have download git source code, compiled and installed it in my home directory. When I use git svn clone to clone the svn repository I got this error: Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC...

I searched on the internet and got the answer that is subversion perl binding is not installed. So I try to install this tool in my home directory (due to I have no root privilege) but I can't find the source code. I only get the deb package with is not suitable for me. Is there any one has the same problem? Or do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the SVN/Core.pm module from CPAN www.cpan.org. It will be called Alien::SVN and will be a .tar archive.

> Alien::SVN is a wrapper to install the Perl bindings for subversion,
>   also known as SVN::Core. If your module needs SVN::Core it can depend
>   on SVN::Core normally, then CPAN clients can resolve the dependency
>   normally via Alien::SVN.

There are numerous stackoverflow answers on how to install and run it locally.

Or google install perl module locally

[How can I use a new Perl module without install permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions)

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw the DESCRIPTION section and I find "It comes with a copy of Subversion 1.8.11". Does this means my svn version should be 1.8.11? My currently svn version is 1.6.17, however I can't find the Alien::SVN 1.6.17

Comment: There apepars to be a 1.6.12 client    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552808/how-do-i-install-perls-svnclient

I would say install the current Alien::SVN and give it a try.  Well written software should be backwards compatible.  If you need to, stroll through some files and see if you can modify a variable to point it at your current svn.

If you have enough room in your sandbox, you could download your own copy of perl and install the modules as needed.